# How to emit items from a list with delay in RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using Retrofit to get bookmarks from REST API:

```
public interface BookmarkService {
    @GET("/bookmarks")
    Observable<List<Bookmark>> bookmarks();
}
```

Now I would like to emit each item from this list with delay.

I did something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158245/how-to-emit-items-from-a-collection-with-delay-in-rxjava) in Java, but `onCompleted` is never triggered.

```
private Observable<Bookmark> getBookmarks() {
    return getBookmarkService().bookmarks()
         .flatMap(new Func1<List<Bookmark>, Observable<Bookmark>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Bookmark> call(List<Bookmark> bookmarks) {
                Observable<Bookmark> resultObservable = Observable.never();
                for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.size(); i++) {
                    List<Bookmark> chunk = bookmarks.subList(i, (i + 1));
                    resultObservable = resultObservable.mergeWith(Observable.from(chunk).delay(1000 * i, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                }

                return resultObservable;
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Usage:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
getBookmarks()
    .subscribe(new Observer<Bookmark>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Timber.i("Completed");
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Timber.i("Error: %s", e.toString());
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Bookmark bookmark) {
            Timber.i("Bookmark: %s", bookmark.toString());
            mBookmarksAdapter.addItem(bookmark);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you use a merge operation, onCompleted will be call if all Observables are completed. but `Observable.never()` will never complete. Use `Observable.empty()` instead.

According to your code, your want to emit sublist with delay. The sublist contains only one element

What you can do : flatmap your list, to emit each items. Buffer it to build a list from items, then use a delay.

```
private Observable<Bookmark> getBookmarks() {
    return getBookmarkService().bookmarks()
                               .flatMap((bookmarks) -> Observable.from(bookmarks)
      .buffer(1)
      .scan(new Pair(0, null), (ac, value) -> new Pair(acu.index + 1, value)
      .flatMap(pair -> Observable.just(pair.value).delay(pair.index, SECONDS)) 
                               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

it might work (not tested)